# Use Grafana tag as Alias with space in tag name string?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have a Grafana dashboard, with an InfluxDB data source.
I want to set up a custom Alias. However, my tags are supposed to be *human readable* therefore have spaces in them...

Like this, the tags just render to `undefined`... Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out: `[[tag_Tag With Space]]`
([source](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/influxdb/))

Answer (score 0):

for example: if you have a tag named `host`, you can write as

```
myMetric of [[tag_host]]
```

so the patterns is

```
[[tag_${yourTag}}]]
```

replace your tag with `${yourTag}`

this this grafana official doc

https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/influxdb/#alias-patterns